# Finding average with shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Let my input be lines of numbers, separated by spaces. Each line can have any number of numbers. There can be any number of lines. I have to find the average of all the numbers and display it up to 4 decimals.

For Example:  Let the name of script file be avg.sh then

```
$ printf "1 2 3 4\n 5 6     7 8 9\n 10 -8" | ./avg.sh
4.2727
```

What I have done so far:

```
#! bin/sh
sum=0
for i in $*
do
sum=`expr $sum + $i`
done
avg=`expr $sum / $n`
echo Average=$avg
```

This is not working as I described. Any ideas?

Comment: n is not initialised

Comment: Oh right! Can I use i instead of n?

Comment: No, since i represents the numbers and not the index

Comment: `expr` (and `$(( ))` expressions) can't do floating point calculations. You'll have to use bc or awk.

Comment: Your script expects numbers as parameters but your example provides them on stdin

Comment: @lucineo : Your script expects parameters (`$*`), but you don't pass any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum=0
n=0
for i in $*
do
sum=`expr $sum + $i`
n=`expr $n + 1`
done
avg=`expr $sum / $n`
echo Average=$avg
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk:

```
printf "1 2 3 4\n 5 6     7 8 9\n 10 -8" \
    | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;++i) {sum+=$i; ++n}} END {printf "%.4f\n", sum/n}'
```

This loops over all fields or each line, updating both `sum` and `n`, then prints the sum.

Answer (score -1):

$(( )) can certainly do floating point, but you have to use 'typeset -F' to declare the variables:

```
    typeset -F avg sum
    sum=0
    while read buff           # reading the stdin
      do
        set -A nums ${buff}   # put stdin into indexed array
     done
    for ((i=0 ; i<${#nums[*]} ; i++))   # over the array elements
      do
        (( sum += ${nums[${i}]} ))
     done
    ((avg = sum/i))
    echo $i
    echo Average=$avg


            echo "1 2 3 4 5 6     7 8 9 10 -8" | ./foo
            Average=4.2727272727
```

Also, notice the gyrations to use stdin data to parameters (the array business)

Edited to add:  @BenjaminW  ksh Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01

Comment: What shell are you using? In Bash, `typeset -F` is "restrict display to function names only". Bash's `$(( ))` can't to floating point arithmetic. Are you using zsh?